# Manage include order of <WinSock2.h> and <Windows.h>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have project that has 2 includes of `<Windows.h>.` Project compiles fine, but now I need to include `<winsock2.h>`. According to my understanding to avoid redefinition problem described in many [places][1] I need to follow rule - `include <winsock2.h> befor each <Windows.h>`. I have done this in both places in my project, but got redefinition problem anyway. Why my understanding regarding simple `rule <winsock2.h> befor each <Windows.h>` gets wrong?

Error:

```
Error   32  error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\ws2def.h    212
Error   33  error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\ws2def.h    390
Error   34  error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ',' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\ws2def.h    390
Error   40  error C2011: 'sockaddr_in' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\ws2def.h    583
Error   41  error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  132
Error   43  error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  176
Error   44  error C2011: 'hostent' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  232
Error   45  error C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  245
Error   46  error C2011: 'servent' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  252
Error   47  error C2011: 'protoent' : 'struct' type redefinition    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  264
Error   48  error C2011: 'WSAData' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  360
Error   49  error C2011: 'sockproto' : 'struct' type redefinition   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  458
Error   50  error C2011: 'linger' : 'struct' type redefinition  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  500
Error   58  error C2375: 'accept' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1578
Error   59  error C2375: 'bind' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1600
Error   60  error C2375: 'closesocket' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1619
Error   61  error C2375: 'connect' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1638
Error   62  error C2375: 'ioctlsocket' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1659
Error   63  error C2375: 'getpeername' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1680
Error   64  error C2375: 'getsockname' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1701
Error   65  error C2375: 'getsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1724
Error   66  error C2375: 'htonl' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1745
Error   67  error C2375: 'htons' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1762
Error   68  error C2375: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1780
Error   69  error C2375: 'inet_ntoa' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1797
Error   70  error C2375: 'listen' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1815
Error   71  error C2375: 'ntohl' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1833
Error   72  error C2375: 'ntohs' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1850
Error   73  error C2375: 'recv' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1870
Error   74  error C2375: 'recvfrom' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1895
Error   75  error C2375: 'select' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1921
Error   76  error C2375: 'send' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1945
Error   77  error C2375: 'sendto' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1970
Error   78  error C2375: 'setsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  1996
Error   79  error C2375: 'shutdown' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2018
Error   80  error C2375: 'socket' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2039
Error   81  error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2063
Error   82  error C2375: 'gethostbyname' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2083
Error   83  error C2375: 'gethostname' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2101
Error   84  error C2375: 'getservbyport' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2121
Error   85  error C2375: 'getservbyname' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2141
Error   86  error C2375: 'getprotobynumber' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2160
Error   87  error C2375: 'getprotobyname' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2178
Error   88  error C2375: 'WSAStartup' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2200
Error   89  error C2375: 'WSACleanup' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2219
Error   90  error C2375: 'WSASetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2236
Error   91  error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2253
Error   92  error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2270
Error   93  error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2287
Error   94  error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2304
Error   95  error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2321
Error   96  error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2343
Error   97  error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2370
Error   98  error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2396
Error   99  error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2421
Error   100 error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2446
Error   101 error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2473
Error   102 error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest' : redefinition; different linkage  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2496
Error   103 error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\winsock2.h  2517
```

Comment: No, you understand the rule correctly. It's probably just that in some file the include order is still mixed.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us *what* errors you get, and *where*. When posting questions regarding build errors of any kind, always include the complete and unedited error output, preferably by copy-pasting the full build log into the question body.

Comment: In the duplicate link there are other solutions that you may try.

Comment: If you are using precompiled headers (i.e. `stdafx.h`) then make sure that the order is correct there first and foremost.

Comment: I have updated question body with errors. Project is not using precompiled headers.

Comment: You still have a translation unit that #includes windows.h too early.  Find it with the /showIncludes compiler option.

Comment: /showIncludes displays two places regarding windows.h inclusion. And this confused me, because suddenly I found many places with #include <windows.h> with search tool . Why this is not shown on output? By the way, if I do _WINSOCKAPI_  in preprocessor definition it solves problem. But I place at the top of two places founded by /showincludes it doesn't helps